# Return records between now and previous week

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL query in oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT s.singleid,s.titel,a.naam,s.taal,SUM(b.aantal) AS "AANTAL VERKOCHT"
  FROM singles s
  JOIN artiesten a on a.artiestid = s.artiestid
  JOIN bestellingen b on b.singleid = s.singleid
  GROUP BY s.singleid,s.titel,a.naam,s.taal,b.datum
  ORDER BY sum(b.aantal) DESC
)

WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

This works, but I need to return only the records where b.datum is between the time now, and previous week.
How do I do this?

Comment: What's the previous week?  7 days ago?  The previous Sunday?

Comment: also which column is the date in? and is it a date/timestamp datatype or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a [BETWEEN](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php/) clause to your where:

```
WHERE b.datum between SYSDATE - 6 AND SYSDATE
```

Comment: For first day of week use **trunc(sysdate,'D')**

Comment: @chris: you expression will return the preceding **eight** days' worth of data, not seven. If 'now' is the 14th of the month, subtracting 7 days will give you the 7th of the month. The inclusive range 7 <= x <= 14 has a range of 8, not 7.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to extract from the BESTELLINGEN table only those rows where [datum] is greater than or equal to (today at midnight minus 7 days) and less than or equal to 'now' (or less than tomorrow at midnight, according to your requirement). I would probably make this set of Bestellingen rows an inline view and join the other tables to it, and then do your grouping.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server the syntax is:

AND (b.datum > DATEADD(week, -1, GetDate()) and b.datum < GetDate())

I would assume the syntax is the same, or very similar, in Oracle.

Comment: sadly, the handling of date and time values is one of the least standard bits of SQL. Oracle's date/time bits are nothing like those of SQL Server.

Comment: Date handling is totally different in Oracle.